# How to verify if a variable is empty in python

Tags: python, string

I'm working with data in .csv format and want to set all the empty cells to the value of an empty string.

The problem that I'm facing is that those files have been manipulated for several people in different environments, hence there are various different junk values on these cells, such as:

```
' '
'NaN'
'nan'
'\n'
'   '
```

And so on.

I'm looking for a standard way to identify all of these types of "junk values."

Comment: `if yourStringVar.strip():` ?

Comment: it doesn't work for 'NaN'

Answer (score 4):

Use .strip() to remove whitespace, and then check if the value is one you want to ignore:

```
if value.strip() in ['', 'NaN', 'nan']:
    # ignore this value
```

Or, make it case-insensitive:

```
if value.strip().lower() in ['', 'nan']:
    # ignore this value
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`isspace`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.isspace) function which would eliminate whitespace values like `'  '` and `'\n'` but would not handle values like `'NaN'` or `'nan'`. There isn't really a standard way to deal with these, so in addition to using `isspace` I would also create a blacklist, e.g.:

`blacklist = ['NaN', 'nan'] # add more as needed`

Then use `isspace()` plus your `blacklist` to filter out unwanted values.

Answer (score 0):

You could read the csv into a Pandas DataFrame, and then use `DataFrame.fillna()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think [pandas.replace](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) would be a good alternative for your problem.

Following are some sample codes:

```
import pandas as pd
# sample data
dic = {'a':['NAN', "", "NaN"], 'b':["", "nan", '\n'], 'c':[1,'2','3']}
df = pd.DataFrame(dic)

replace_list = ['NaN', '', 'nan', '\n']
df_clean = df.replace(replace_list, '')
df_clean
```

You can import csv data to Pandas and do the same thing.

Hope it helps.